# Using font CMR12

Tags: fonts, thesis

I want to use the font "CMR12"
I googled it but didn't get any helpful results.

Questions:

1) How do I change the font in my latex to this font?

2) What happens to the math equations if I use this font? will it screw everything up?

System info:
Mac OS X el capitan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`documentclass[12pt]{…}` and no font loading, no `T1` font encoding. `cmr` is the default font. However, note if you need accented letters, you'd have better write `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: this doesn't usually use `cmr12`, but it *will* have math set up properly.

Comment: Hi @barbarabeeton, what do you mean by "this doesn't usually use `cmr12` "?

Comment: @barbara beeton: same question. The default font is `cmr`, isn't it?

Comment: the computer modern fonts have different design sizes, so `cmr10` glyphs have slightly different shapes than the corresponding glyphs in `cmr12`.  for those two sizes the difference is minimal and barely noticeable, but if you compare `cmr7` or `cmr5` you can notice quite distinct differences.  the smaller sizes are relatively wider, so they can be read more clearly in sub- and superscripts, and won't fade away so quickly in photocopying.

Comment: Technically, you need neither fontenc nor lmodern in order to use accented characters.

Comment: Yes, except you'll have hyphenation problems.